# Yii2.0 CRUD-Generator doesn't read out foreign keys, at all

Tags: yii2

I just created three modells using FORM-Generator. Furthermore, I created following files, using CRUD-Generator:

```
generated controllers\BewerbungenController.php
generated models\BewerbungenSearch.php
generated views\bewerbungen\_form.php
generated views\bewerbungen\_search.php
generated views\bewerbungen\create.php
generated views\bewerbungen\index.php
generated views\bewerbungen\update.php  generated views\bewerbungen\view.php
done
```

Unfortunatley,Yii2.0 just reads out table as it is, without recognizing foreign keys in it. How can I solve this problem?

---

Can I use any extensions or widgets of generator, or do I have to programm querys like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT datum,firma,art,stadt,plz,strasse_nr,ansprech_person,email,notiz 
AS feedback,bemerkung FROM bewerbungen JOIN rechtsform
ON bewerbungen.rechtsart=rechtsform.id_recht
JOIN nachricht ON bewerbungen.feedback=nachricht.id_message ORDER BY datum DESC";


namespace app\models;

use Yii;

/**
 * This is the model class for table "bewerbungen".
 *
 * @property integer $bew_id
 * @property string $datum
 * @property string $firma
 * @property integer $rechtsart
 * @property string $stadt
 * @property integer $plz
 * @property string $strasse_nr
 * @property string $ansprech_person
 * @property string $email
 * @property integer $feedback
 * @property string $bemerkung
 *
 * @property Nachricht $feedback0
 * @property Rechtsform $rechtsart0
 */
class Bewerbungen extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'bewerbungen';
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['datum', 'firma', 'stadt', 'plz', 'email'], 'required'],
            [['datum'], 'safe'],
            [['rechtsart', 'plz', 'feedback'], 'integer'],
            [['firma', 'stadt', 'strasse_nr', 'ansprech_person'], 'string', 'max' => 100],
            [['email'], 'string', 'max' => 50],
            [['bemerkung'], 'string', 'max' => 150],
            [['feedback'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => Nachricht::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['feedback' => 'id_message']],
            [['rechtsart'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => Rechtsform::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['rechtsart' => 'id_recht']],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'bew_id' => 'Bew ID',
            'datum' => 'Datum',
            'firma' => 'Firma',
            'rechtsart' => 'Rechtsart',
            'stadt' => 'Stadt',
            'plz' => 'Plz',
            'strasse_nr' => 'Strasse Nr',
            'ansprech_person' => 'Ansprech Person',
            'email' => 'Email',
            'feedback' => 'Feedback',
            'bemerkung' => 'Bemerkung',
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getFeedback0()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Nachricht::className(), ['id_message' => 'feedback']);
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getRechtsart0()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Rechtsform::className(), ['id_recht' => 'rechtsart']);
    }
}
```

As it seems, public function getFeedback0() and public function getRechtsart0() are totally dispensable!

That's the table, whose foreign keys won't read out:

```
CREATE TABLE `bewerbungen` (
  `bew_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `datum` date NOT NULL,
  `firma` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_german2_ci NOT NULL,
  `rechtsart` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `stadt` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_german2_ci NOT NULL,
  `plz` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `strasse_nr` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_german2_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `ansprech_person` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_german2_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_german2_ci NOT NULL,
  `feedback` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `bemerkung` varchar(150) COLLATE utf8_german2_ci DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_german2_ci;

ALTER TABLE `bewerbungen`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `bewerbungen_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`feedback`) REFERENCES `nachricht` (`id_message`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `bewerbungen_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`rechtsart`) REFERENCES `rechtsform` (`id_recht`);
```

Comment: Gii automatically creathes the relationships corresponding to your foreign keys, and yes, you can use them later without programming sql manually. Post the structure definition of your table to see whether there is an error in it

Comment: Obviously, Gii doesn't automatically create relationships to my foreign keys!The foreign keys(see below) feedback and rechtsart won't read out! Do I have to programm manually, or can I use a widget?

Comment: 1) Do not post additions to your question as answers, just edit your question. 2) Post only the structure of the tables. 3) Ok, I see you have the FKs. In Gii, in the model generator, there is a select box titled 'Generate relations', that should have value 'All relations'. Does it?

Comment: Yes. I created models using parameter as U suggested. By the way:This is the default value!

Comment: Can you post IN THE QUESTION (edit it) the code of the generated model for the table `bewerbungen`?

Comment: All right. I posted generated code of model for table 'bewerbungen'.

Comment: As expected, the relationships methods are right there, `getFeedback0` and `getRechtsart0`

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not able to move this problem to chat.However, it's still unsolved!The two automatically generated  method don't, what they should do!

Comment: Why do you mean by incorrect?

Comment: Because they should read out foreign keys,but they don't!! So, they are syntactically correct,but logically incorrect!